# How can I display an image on a view which the name is on session variable?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a view where I store the images to storage/app/public and I also have done:

`php artisan storage:link`

So I can use the asset to retrieve the files from storage.

```html
<img src="{{ asset('storage/{{$_SESSION['empresa']}}.png') }}"
     alt="{{$_SESSION['empresa']}}" 
     style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;">
```

Which is the easiest way to get the file with the file name stored in session?

Comment: Is using sessions in blade against MVC? I would rather pass it as a variable from controller and use `compact()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the session function helper instead of the global variable

```html
<img src="{{ asset("storage/" . session('empresa') . ".png" ) }}" alt="{{ session('empresa') }}"
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;">
```

Hope this helps

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ')' (View: C:\Users\ACC\Desktop\projeto\acc\resources\views\su.blade.php)

Comment: Updated, try again

Comment: I have done like this:<img src="{{ asset("storage/" . $_SESSION['empresa'] . ".png" ) }}" alt="{{ session('empresa') }}"
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;">

Answer (score 1):

If you have some data in session storage, the most easy way in Laravel is using global helper:

laravel.com/docs/5.8/session

`{{ session('empresa') }}`

or Facade

`{{ Session::get('empresa')}}`